# Difference between coordinate space and vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am new to linear algebra and was going through [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_space) link, and it made me wonder:

> Is there a technical difference between coordinate space (e.g., $R^n$) and vector space? If not, then why are there 2 terms for the same concept?

Comment: Do you know what it means for two vector spaces to be isomorphic? Every $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is isomorphic to $F^n$.

Comment: Vector spaces can be more general than a coordinate space, e.g. a vector space of certain kinds of functions.

Comment: Just  to say words. A coordinate space is what you get when you take a vector space and "pick coordinates" (e.g. pick a basis).

Comment: @OckhamsRazor coordinate spaces are made of concrete vectors from the field. An abstract vector space allows for way weirder stuff, like polynomials, matrices or linear transformations. These are not just $n$-tuples of numbers from the base field.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Any polynomial of degree $d$ can be naturally identified with a $d+1$-tuple of scalars. Similarily, any matrix $n\times m$ can be identified with an $nm$-tuple.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I am well aware of that, but being identified and being the same object are not the same. There is a "technical difference" they are different point sets. I totally agree, linear algebraically we can identify $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & -b \\ b & a \end{array} \right]$ and $a+ib$ and $(a,b)$ and $a+bx$, but, they're not the same object.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Sure. Then I interpreted the question in a different way.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I suppose my interpretation mostly stems from the students who insist on the isomorphism without understanding it... but, your answer is reasonable.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I think it is worth noting as you say how other "versions" of the spaces may carry more structure. I would obviously work with matrices rather than with $mn$-tuples. Simiarily, polynomials might serve better purposes than $d+1$-tuples, and so on. But I don't know if I am the appropriate person to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that if a vector space has a finite basis it is said to be finite dimensional, and the dimension is defined to be the number of vectors that make up this basis. Basis are (possibly finite) sets of vectors that span the vector space and are linearly independent. One can prove that every vector in said vector space can be written in one and only one way as a linear combination of these basis vectors. Say $V$ is a $K$ vector space with basis $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. Then if we have $$v=\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n$$

we write $(v)_B=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ and say $v$ has coordinates $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ in the basis $B$. This immediately gives a mapping $V\to F^n$ given by $$v\mapsto (v)_B$$

This is the same as mapping each basis vector $v_i$ to $$(0,0,\ldots,\underbrace{1}_i,\ldots,0)$$
which entirely determines the transformation.

Note that $0\mapsto (0,0,\ldots,0)$; that $(v+w)_B=(v)_B+(w)_B$ and $(\lambda v)_B=\lambda (v)_B$ so this is a linear transformation, which gives an isomorphism between $V$ and $F^n$. This means $V$ and $F^n$ are essentially the same as vector spaces, that is, "there is only one vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $F$ up to isomorphism."

Answer (score 0):

For a given dimension $n$ and a given field $k$, there is only one vector space of dimension $n$ over $k$ up to isomorphism, and this vector space is $k^n$, called the coordinate vector space.